# Why my html code get duplicated on index page after adding {nav} placeholder in it

Tags: php, html, duplicates, placeholder

When i put a placeholder {nav} in index.tpl.html a dynamic navigation works on home button nut all other buttons get duplicated. This is the code in index-nav.module. Any ideas why? (theres a picture down there)

```
[//$detmen='<ul class="nav navbar-nav">';
$detmen='';
foreach($aHauptNavi as $hana){

    if ( $ana -> pageHasSubs( $hana -> id ) AND $hana -> id!=53) {
        $supas = $ana -> getSubPages( $hana -> id );

        $detmen.='<li class="no'.$hana->id.' nav-item '.(($hana->id==$id)?'active':'').' dropdown ">
        <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" id="homeDropdown'.$hana->id.'" href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
        '.$hana->navigacija.'</a>';
        $detmen.='<div aria-labelledby="homeDropdown'.$hana->id.'" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right ">';
        for ($j = 0; $j < count( $supas ); $j++) {
            $detmen.='<a target="_self" href="/'.$supas[$j]->SEFtitle.'.html">'.$supas[$j]->navigacija.'</a>';
        }
        $detmen.='</div>
                    </li>';


    }else{`enter code here`

            $detmen.='<li class="no'.$hana->id.' nav-item '.(($hana->id==$id)?'active':'').'">
            <a class="nav-link " href="/'.$hana->SEFtitle.'.html">'.$hana->navigacija.' 
            '.(($hana->id==$id)?'<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>':'').'</a></li>';
    }

}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You should probably note that backticks have a special meaning in PHP. They act as an [execution operator](http://php.net/language.operators.execution). In your code **}else{`enter code here`** will execute everything between the backticks into your shell and return the result.

Comment: Yea i just had to delete all html code in index.tpl XD Big thanks !!